# 403 Error when accessing HTML file on FTP

Tags: php, html, header

I am having difficulty accessing the **index.html** code on FTP. When I open it, an HTML structure appears with "Directory access is forbidden." written on it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Directory access is forbidden.</p>
 
</body>
</html>
```

I need to change the website header, but I can't find any other alternative.

There is also **index.php** and **home.php** code, but I can't find the head or header section inside them.

I just started learning front-end, especially PHP, so I apologize if I am asking something so simple, I was just thrown into this language and have almost no experience.

I wanted to change my website landing page header, but it seems like I don't have permission. Searched all the files to find it, but couldn't, so I'm asking for help.

NOTE: It is a institutional website and it have been online since 2013.

Comment: Files such as "index.html", "index.php", "index.asp" and "home.php" are just common patterns. There's no global rule that says when you go "https://example.com/" that "index.html" will be used. In modern CMS sites it is very that zero files exist on disk representing a single "page", and instead there are templates that build things dynamically. Is the site you are working on CMS-based?

Comment: I found out what was happening, but thank you so much for the awnser. The website is a MVC architecture, but I will search for and find out what a CMS-based site is.